# How can I download and save image robot framework in python?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have a problem and I couldn't figure out how to get around this. I am automating with the robot framework python. I'm going to google.com. I want to download and save the google image.

```
*** Variables ***
${b}  chrome
${url}          https://www.google.com/
${avatar}       xpath://img[@alt='Google']


*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    open browser  ${url}  ${b}
    maximize browser window
    sleep  1 seconds
    page should contain image  ${avatar}
    element should be visible  ${avatar}
    open context menu  ${avatar}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `run process` keyword from Process library and `curl` command. Downloaded file will be in EXEC_DIR with name `logo.png`.

This work for me:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${b}  chrome
${url}          https://www.google.com/
${avatar}       xpath://img[@alt='Google']


*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    SeleniumLibrary.open browser  ${url}  ${b}
    maximize browser window
    sleep  1 seconds
    page should contain image  ${avatar}
    element should be visible  ${avatar}
    ${image_url}=  Get Element Attribute  ${avatar}  src
    log to console  ${image_url}
    Run Process  curl  -o  logo.png  ${image_url}
    close all browsers
```

Comment: This method worked. Thank you. So how can I upload to this

Comment: @reverseengineer I do not understand "So how can I upload to this". If this solved your question, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I wanted to say. How can I upload the downloaded image?

Comment: @reverseengineer selenium has keyword for that: https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File